# Output index of hash in array of hashes?

Tags: ruby

This might be a silly question, but I'm struggling with outputting the positions of an array of hashes I have.

If I have an array of hashes, we'll call `some_array`, that looks like this:

```
some_array =
 [{:id=>7, :people=>["Bob B", "Jimmy J"], :product=>"product1"},
 {:id=>2, :people=>["Sally S"], :product=>"product1"},
 {:id=>5, :people=>["Hank H", "Stan C"], :product=>"product2"},
 {:id=>3, :people=>["Sue T"], :product=>"product2"},
 {:id=>4, :people=>["Anne W"], :product=>"product3"}]
```

I then iterate though `some_array` like so:

```
some_array.select{|p| p[:product] == "product2"]}.each do |product|
     product[:people].join("<br>")         
     product[:product]
```

Which outputs like:

```
Hank K      product 2
Stan C

Sue T       product 2
```

How would I go about outputting the index/position of each hash in the array?

Would I be able to do something along the lines of:

```
some_array.select{|p| p[:product] == "product2"]}.each do |product|
     product.index
     product[:people].join("<br>")         
     product[:product]
```

And get:

```
2   Hank K      product2
    Stan C

3   Sue T       product2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [each_with_index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) and format to your use case:

```
  some_array.each_with_index do |product, index|
    if product[:product] == "product2"
      p index
      p product
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you can chain methods on [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html), which allows you to call `with_index` before you `select` to get the original index of the element:

```
some_array.each_with_index.select do |element, _|
  element[:product] == "product2"
end.each do |product, index|
  p [index, product[:people].join("<br />"), product[:product]]
end

# outputs:
# [2, "Hank H<br />Stan C", "product2"]
# [3, "Sue T", "product2"]
```

While you can call `select.with_index`, and it may be tempting to do so, the index won't carry over into the `each`, because `select` returns the elements that matched and doesn't care about the input. When you call `each_with_index` (or `each.with_index`), though, you now have a new Enumerable which is each element in your array with its index in that array, and `select` ends up returning these new array elements:

```
some_array.each.with_index.select { |element, _| element[:product] == "product2" }
# => [[{:id=>5, :people=>["Hank H", "Stan C"], :product=>"product2"}, 2],
      [{:id=>3, :people=>["Sue T"], :product=>"product2"}, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fmt_str_first = "%-4d%-10s%10s"
fmt_str_rest  = "#{' '*4}%-10s"

some_array.each_with_index do |h,i|
  next unless h[:product] == "product2"
  first, *rest = h[:people]
  puts fmt_str_first % [i, first, "product2"]
  rest.each { |name| puts fmt_str_rest % name }
  puts
end

2   Hank H      product2
    Stan C

3   Sue T       product2
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf). Note that `%-10s` in the format string means that the corresponding entry, a string (`s`), is to be left-adjusted (`-`) in a field of width `10`. `%10s` would cause the entry to be right-adjusted.

Comment: My casual reading of the question led me to believe that the OP wanted to print a table having the format shown in the question. Me bad (or should that be “my bad”?}.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use `each_with_index` and skip the item you don't need

```
some_array.each_with_index do |product, index|
  next if product[:product] != "product2"
  index
  product[:people].join("<br>")
  product[:product]
end
```